# Compilation error: org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType Compilation error

Tags: java, jsp, web-applications, tomcat9

I have been asked to work on a very old webapp in my company. The webapp consists of only JSP and it was running on older version of tomcat instance. Now I have migrated it to tomcat9 and just after starting the server, I get the below error msg in catalina.out of tomcat:

```
SEVERE [https-jsse-nio-10.92.145.145-8888-exec-5] org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType Compilation error
 org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:342)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:211)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:166)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2187)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:974)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1164)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:366)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:623)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:392)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:448)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:350)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:334)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:625)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:498)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:796)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1372)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have replaced the *`jasper-jdt.jar`* with new *`ecj-4.6.1.jar`*. Still cannot figure out, whats going wrong in it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The eclipse compiler for java is not an upgrade to any jsp jar. Does the project have any dependency management? And how old is old?

Comment: There is no dependency management for this project.
This is 8 years old application

Comment: It's not trivial upgrading a technology stack - it's especially not trivial with no dependency management. I hope you're not on fixed bid.

Comment: I had the same problem and I just copied the ecj-4.6.1.jar file in to the Tomact 6 lib folder (without replacing it with jasper-jdt.jar) and it works fine now for me.